# Initialize variable inside class without constructor

Tags: java

Here is some simple java code .

```
class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        TestClass c = new TestClass();
        System.out.println(c.x);
    }
}

class TestClass {
    {
        x = 2;
    }
    int x = 1;
}
```

I am getting the answer 1. Why?
Is there no constructor used to initialize?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TestClass is compiled to be equivalent to this:

```
class TestClass {
    {
        this.x = 2;
    }

    int x;

    {
        this.x = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really - it is compiled to have a no args constructor that contains those two lines.

Comment: I don't think the code is compiled to this. The initializers are moved to the constructor added by the compiler.

Comment: @user3007882 Please remove word *compiled*, leave *equivalent* and all is ok :)

Answer (score 5):

The order of execution of initializer blocks, and variable initializer is specified in [JLS § 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5):

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the
>   result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new
>   object using the following procedure:
>
> [...]
>
> 4 Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable
>   initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the
>   **left-to-right order in which they appear textually** in the source code
>   for the class. [..]

So, the initializer blocks and variable initializers executed in order in which they appear in the source file. If you move the variable declaration, `int x = 1;`, before the initializer block, you'll get the result `2`.

Technically, your `Test` class is compiled to the this:

```
class TestClass {
    int x;

    public TestClass() {
        super();
        x = 2;
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

For actual bytecode you can run `javap -c` command.

Answer (score 1):

Because it would be compiled To :

```
class TestClass {
    int x; 

    TestClass(){
        this.x = 2;
        this.x = 1;
    }
}
```